# sql operation date query to find date between the to date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
rommbookinfo
(
   hotel_id
   , room_no
   , start_date
   , end_date
);
```

Now I have to perform a query to find rooms for the given hotel (hotel id) that are not  booked in the date range( ie in between date1 and date2)

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_roombook
WHERE hotel_id = '2'
   AND start_date NOT BETWEEN 12/17/2011 AND 12/19/2011 
   OR end_date NOT BETWEEN 12/17/2011 AND 12/19/2011
```

but it throws the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
''SELECT * FROM tbl_roombook WHERE hotel_id='2' AND start_date' at line 1
```

Comment: what is your question? what is not working ? what is your expected input/output?

Comment: please put your query with values as well tell me your table structure for date fields, and show me your code, and show me your error while u execute this query directly in phpmyadmin

Comment: @Boruah - the syntax error is because the dates need to be in quotes.  It doesn't matter - your query won't work anyway.  Charles Bretana's solution looks like it should work.  Please try it out, and mark it "accepted" if it does!

Comment: Where is this code being called from, I think the single quotes are causing you a problem

Comment: looks your table field type is varchar ???

Comment: in one shot post all your information ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
  Select distinct room_no
  From tbl_roombook rb
  Where hotel_id = '$h_id' 
    And Not Exists
      (Select * From tbl_roombook
       Where hotel_id = rb.Hotel_id
           And room_No = rb.room_no
           And start_date <= $date2
           And end_Date >= $date1)
```

Comment: Hi  Charles Bretana, when the date field is varchar, your query will work

Comment: because @Boruah passing date like 12/17/2011, so query consider this as string, please clarify it

Comment: No start_date,end_Date  are not varchar rather they are in date formate in the table

Comment: Im not gamiliar with MySql, but it should convert datestrings in query parameters to dates automagically as necessary. If your database table has these columns as varcvhars, then good luck.